# error in xml file "extends YouTubeBaseActivity as it context "

Tags: xml, android-studio, youtube-api

I'm Writing an app using YouTube API, while writing the xml file I got this error-

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
because of-
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context."

so I have done it and my activity now extends YouTubeBaseActivity but i still got the error for some reason.
here is the xml file-

```html
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.daniel.musiclyrics.SongScreen"
    android:background="#ffff9d91"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Song Name"
        android:id="@+id/SongNameT"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#f03e3e3e"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
 

 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/YoutubePlayer"
    />
   </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the class head-

```js
package com.example.daniel.musiclyrics;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


import java.net.URI;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.List;


public class SongScreen extends YouTubeBaseActivity  implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{
  
}
```

if anyone can tell me why android studio keep sending this error could help me a lot.

Comment: is this a compiler error complaining about the xml file or the SongScreen class which extends from YouTubeBaseActivity

Comment: the error is complaining on the xml file. the preview can't show the YouTube player view.

Comment: I have an app that has a youtube player, I will be more than happy to post the xml file some of my code to see if it solves your issue.  My implementation which is based on the documentations and one of the samples work fine

Comment: on the other hand, my xml file is simple, it does not use tools:context, I wonder if this is the issue.  Maybe remove  tools:context="com.example.daniel.musiclyrics.SongScreen" and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: @DanielS Did you get to know the answer? If so please share the code.

Comment: Please any one can give clear answer about this how i can resolve this layout problem

Comment: The youtube player works fine for me, but the warning persist in the xml. You found any solution?